# Not getpath while Crop image Before Upload

Tags: android, image

I crop image from camra using this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");  
intent.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CropImage");  
File file = new File(filePath);  
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);  
intent.setData(uri);  
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");  
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);  
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);  
intent.putExtra("outputX", 96);  
intent.putExtra("outputY", 96);  
intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);  
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);                                  
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CROP_ICON);
```

from this i have solve my problem for croping image but now i want path for this croped image how to get actual path from this image. i already get path from gallery cropped image but occurred problem with camra image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer this question to do that :

[How to Get Correct Path After Cropping the Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534625/how-to-get-correct-path-after-cropping-the-image)
first answer show i to do that